# Nested NSDictionaries implementation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on app that stores plist with dictionary implementation as:

```
Name    abc
Address def
ID      123
```

The above is achieved easily but now i want to append and implement on second account entry as:

```
First
 Name    abc
 Address def
 ID      123
Second
 Name    abc
 Address def
 ID      123
```

...

Can anybody help kindly

Comment: An NSDictionary can contain any other Objective-C object, including an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just looking for how to create an array of dictionaries?

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

NSDictionary *first = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"abc",@"Name",@"def",@"Address",[NSNumber numberWithInt:123],@"ID", nil];

NSDictionary *second = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"abc",@"Name",@"def",@"Address",[NSNumber numberWithInt:123],@"ID", nil];

[array addObject:first];
[array addObject:second];
// [array addObject:another] and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it as `NSMutableArray` which contains `NSDictionary`s